# How Do I See All Merges Into Master on Remote

Tags: git

I am trying to see all of the merges into master in the remote repository via my command line. I am trying the command

```
git log --merges --first-parent master --oneline
```

But that isn't getting everything it seems. It only is getting things that happend locally. I have tried `git fetch --all` but that didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

When you fetch from a remote, your repo updates its tracking refs, so origin's master branch shows up locally as `refs/remotes/origin/master`, which you can usually refer to just as `origin/master`.

```
git log --oneline --merges --first-parent origin/master
```

You combine any local work with upstream work however you like, the default is to merge, for carrying a patch series rebase is very popular with good reason. `git pull` is the convenience command for fetching and then doing as usual with what that got you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command for it.

git branch --merged master

Comment: That is just getting me the branches I want to see all of the merge information.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).